# displaying image to listview wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

what do i need to add in my code below?

what i'm doing is to view the images in the listview

so far this is my code

```
<ListView Name="Thumbnails">
   <ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>


foreach (var item in lstImages)
{
  Thumbnails.Items.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(item)));
}
```

what do i need in order to show the images to the listview. the output of the code is only string, i did a search but i don't understand the code i found. thank you

Comment: How about any reaction to the provided answers?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `ItemTemplate` property of the ListView (or a ListBox) to a DataTemplate that contains an `Image` control, and bind the Image control's `Source` property to the collection element.

```
<ListView Name="Thumbnails">
     <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now add `BitmapImage` instances to the `Items` collection of the ListView:

```
foreach (var item in lstImages)
{
    Thumbnails.Items.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(item)));
}
```

Due to built-in automatic type conversion from `string` and `Uri` (and `byte[]`) to `ImageSource`, you could as well just add the image file paths to the `Items` collection:

```
foreach (var item in lstImages)
{
    Thumbnails.Items.Add(item);
}
```

---

As next step you may want to have a view model with an `ObservableCollection<string>` property that holds the image file paths. You would bind the ListView's `ItemsSource` property to this collection.

Answer (score -1):

Add an **Image** element to the ListView:

```
Thumbnails.Items.Add(new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("yourpic.png", UriKind.Relative)) });
```

Answer (score -2):

The ListView's ItemSource should be set to the list of URIs. Then you need to set up an ItemTemplate that contains an image control with the Source bound to the value.

```
ListView.DataTemplate
    ItemTemplate
        Image
```

Comment: This was a briefer version of Clemens answer - you should not have downvoted this answer.